# How does one properly call multiple cat commands from a single bash script?

Tags: shell-script, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to collect text files from multiple subdirectories and concatenate them into a single file per subdirectory. There may be a much better way of doing this but my question is, how does one call multiple cat commands from a bash script? Here is an example:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat "./directory_1/"*.txt > "directory_1.txt"
cat "./directory_2/"*.txt > "directory_2.txt"
```

If I keep all the commands on the same line, seperated by semicolons, it works. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat "./directory_1/"*.txt > "directory_1.txt";cat "./directory_2/"*.txt > "directory_2.txt"
```

But if I need to call say 20 directories, the script becomes very hard to read.

I expected the first example to run each cat command, however, the following error was thrown:

```
line 2: $'\r': command not found
: No such file or directorydirectory2.txt
```

It looks like I have a problem with the newline character. I am trying to run this command on the Ubuntu shell for Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following loop would process every directory under the current directory in the way that you describe:

```
for dir in */; do
    cat "$dir"/*.txt >"${dir%/}.txt"
done
```

The `${dir%/}` thing removes the trailing `/` from `$dir` which is there from the glob match in the loop header.

The error that you get is likely due to writing the script on a Windows machine (with a Windows editor).  Windows (and DOS) text files has a carriage return character before the linefeed character at the end of every line, while Unix text files only has the linefeed character.  You can convert the script to a Unix text file using the `dos2unix` utility.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is spot on in this case. The script was being saved with Windows style line endings "CR/LF" instead of Unix style "LF." Updating the line endings of the bash file fixed the problem.